# I would like to use the querySelector with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I would like to use the querySelector but it does not work. I think I need to put a word in the permissions but I can't find it. It's also possible that my code is bad I'm a beginner in js (If you have something to optimize my code I won't say no ;) ) I am making a calculator and I would like to know when I click on a number.

```
var debugmyextension = 7;
const one = document.querySelector(one);

one.addEventListener('click', event => {
    var debugmyextension = 2;
});

const two = document.querySelector(two);
const three = document.querySelector(three);
const four = document.querySelector(four);
const five = document.querySelector(five);
const six = document.querySelector(six);
const seven = document.querySelector(seven);
const eight = document.querySelector(eight);
const nine = document.querySelector(nine);
const zero = document.querySelector(zero);
```

my manifest file :

```
 {
    "name": "multi-jeu",
    "description": "de Jean Heubel",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,

    "background": {
      "service_worker": "/js/app.js"
    },

    "permissions": [
      "background",
      "storage",
      "clipboardWrite",
      "clipboardRead"
    ],

    "action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "/img/Capture d’écran 2021-09-07 122140.png"

      }
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "/img/Capture d’écran 2021-09-07 122140.png"

    }
 }
```

my error message :

js/app.js:2 (fonction anonyme) :

```
const one = document.querySelector(one);
```

Comment: If "one" is the value of some HTML element's `id` attribute, you can access the element with `document.querySelector("#one")`. Learn lots more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Answer (score 0):

Well, we don't have your HTML, but let me explain `querySelector`, if you have a class in HTML and you want to use it in Javascript, then do `document.querySelector('.class-name')` "class-name is for example the name of your class", for an id, you would do `document.querySelector('#id-name')`,for a whole element you would do `document.querySelector('body')` "body is the element that you want to import" you can see it as you style elements in css.

here is some [documentation](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-queryselector/)that can be helpful

Comment: Hi, I followed your documentation and I have a new error. My chrome extension says that the document is not defined, is it just a js or chrome error? ```let one = document.querySelector(".one");

one.addEventListener('click', event => {
    var debugmyextension = 2;
  });```

Comment: I'm sorry I saw your comment late, is one actually a button a div ? what is the error (I mean the error message)?

Comment: I don't understand the point of your function, you have an `event` argument that you are not using, and also, you have already defined your variable (it means that you have wrotten `var debugmyextension` in the top and then `var debugmyextension` also in the function ), remove that var in the function, because it means that you are defining it again (we only define a variable once in the code), and also, you can use `const` instead of `let`, because it's an HTML element, so it won't change